# How to drop column in your dataset with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Now I'm taking a machine learning course. Now I should import my dataset after I read a "CSV" file to import my dataset I want to drop a column but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `df = df.drop('col_name', axis=1)`

Comment: These kind of questions are easily answered by perusing the docs.

Comment: @omar: I suggest you first try to search for your question in StackOverflow, and only if you do not find an answer, then ask the question. Good luck with your machine learning courses as well! ML is fun!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume LIKES as column, how to drop it?

```
df.drop('LIKES', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `inplace` is not recommended any more, @James's comment above is the recommended way.